# Where is pocofoundationmtd.lib

Tags: vcpkg

I'm trying to get a copy of pocofoundationmtd.lib. It is required for a project that I am working on. I used the command "vcpkg install POCO" which is supposed to build and install the pocofoundationmtd.lib or pocofoundationmt.lib (which I assume that I will also need once I deal with the release version).

I tried building with buildwin.cmd 160. I got this

```
  wepoll.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1
363,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\OptiNetSDK5.0\poco\bin\Net.dll) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property
value (C:\OptiNetSDK5.0\poco\bin\PocoNetd.dll). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, plea
se make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputF
ile). [C:\OptiNetSDK5.0\poco\Net\Net_vs160.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1
365,5): warning MSB8012: TargetName(Net) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (PocoNetd). This may cau
se your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt)
property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile). [C:\OptiNetSDK5.0\poco\Net\Net_vs160.vcxproj]
     Creating library ..\lib\PocoNetd.lib and object ..\lib\PocoNetd.exp
PollSet.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall Poco::SpinlockMutex::
SpinlockMutex(void)" (__imp_??0SpinlockMutex@Poco@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Poco::Net::PollSe
tImpl::PollSetImpl(void)" (??0PollSetImpl@Net@Poco@@QAE@XZ) [C:\OptiNetSDK5.0\poco\Net\Net_vs160.vcxproj]
PollSet.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall Poco::SpinlockMutex::
~SpinlockMutex(void)" (__imp_??1SpinlockMutex@Poco@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0PollSetImpl@Net@P
oco@@QAE@XZ$0 [C:\OptiNetSDK5.0\poco\Net\Net_vs160.vcxproj]
PollSet.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall Poco::SpinlockMu
tex::lock(void)" (__imp_?lock@SpinlockMutex@Poco@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Poco::ScopedLock<c
lass Poco::SpinlockMutex>::ScopedLock<class Poco::SpinlockMutex>(class Poco::SpinlockMutex &)" (??0?$ScopedLock@VSpinlo
ckMutex@Poco@@@Poco@@QAE@AAVSpinlockMutex@1@@Z) [C:\OptiNetSDK5.0\poco\Net\Net_vs160.vcxproj]
    Hint on symbols that are defined and could potentially match:
      "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall Poco::FastMutex::lock(void)" (__imp_?lock@FastMutex@Poco@@QAEXXZ)
      "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall Poco::Mutex::lock(void)" (__imp_?lock@Mutex@Poco@@QAEXXZ)
PollSet.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall Poco::SpinlockMu
tex::unlock(void)" (__imp_?unlock@SpinlockMutex@Poco@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Poco::ScopedLo
ck<class Poco::SpinlockMutex>::~ScopedLock<class Poco::SpinlockMutex>(void)" (??1?$ScopedLock@VSpinlockMutex@Poco@@@Poc
o@@QAE@XZ) [C:\OptiNetSDK5.0\poco\Net\Net_vs160.vcxproj]
    Hint on symbols that are defined and could potentially match:
      "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall Poco::FastMutex::unlock(void)" (__imp_?unlock@FastMutex@Poco@@QAEX
  XZ)
      "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall Poco::Mutex::unlock(void)" (__imp_?unlock@Mutex@Poco@@QAEXXZ)
..\bin\PocoNetd.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals [C:\OptiNetSDK5.0\poco\Net\Net_vs160.vcxproj]
```

Windows 10. Visual Studio 2019. SDK 10.22000

Comment: I tried building with buildwin.cmd 160. I got this

Comment: It looks like I may have gotten the libraries I needed, but there appears to be a problem that someone needs to fix